# Determine if MySQL has been started with skip-grant-tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Is there a way to tell if MySQL has been started with skip-grant-tables within mysql? I can't find anything in `show variables`

I'd like to add a guard to a startup sql script to prevent UDF functions from trying to be created when they can't be (e.g. the docker startup is running setup, etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to exist a variable to determine that.

The following stored procedure can give you some ideas:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `_`.`skip_grant_tables`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `_`.`skip_grant_tables`(OUT `skip_grant` BOOL)
BEGIN
  DECLARE `skip_grant_text` TEXT;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 `skip_grant_text` = MESSAGE_TEXT;
  END;
  SET `skip_grant` := 0;
  GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO ''@'';
  IF (`skip_grant_text` REGEXP '--skip-grant-tables option') THEN
    SET `skip_grant` := 1;
  END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `_`.`skip_grant_tables`(@`skip_grant_tables?`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`skip_grant_tables?`;
+-----------------------+
| @`skip_grant_tables?` |
+-----------------------+
|                     1 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Clever... Sorry for the late accept - I've been on vacation.

Comment: @Stephen: Hope you enjoyed your vacation!